# Is there a method to fetch only first few record from a django database

Tags: django

I am trying to fetch the hotels records from database.I used below query and it worked fine.

```
hotels = models.Hotel.objects.filter(wed=True, county=hotel.county.id)
```

But i want to fetch only first few records(eg:10) rather than fetching multiple records and want to reduce the execution time.... Is there way to that....

Any help will be great....

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hotels = models.Hotel.objects.filter(wed=True, county=hotel.county.id)[:10] # limit to 10 
hotels = models.Hotel.objects.filter(wed=True, county=hotel.county.id)[5:10] # Slicing 6 to 10
```

see [limiting querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)